# eclipse plugin maven integration

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I'm looking for a solution which does not have to be nice. For a simple Showcase I need to add a dependency from project a to project b (a needs b). Project a is managed by maven and gets dependencies from maven, project b is an eclipse plugin project and has depencies to other plugin projects. In project a I need everything from project b. When I add project to the buildpath of project a, I don't get any transitive dependencies from b.
Does anyone know I quick way to get that solved and what am I missing?
Greetings and thanks in advance, karl

Comment: Are you using m2eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If project B isn't mavenized, you won't get its transitive dependencies automagically. In that case, and if project B has its dependencies in a directory, one solution would be to add a MANIFEST.MF to project B with a `Class-Path` entry referencing all dependencies using relative paths. Eclipse would read that file and add all dependent JARs to project A build path.